# Как запретить доступ к файлам некоторых расширений в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Как запретить доступ к файлам некоторых расширений в .htaccess?

Comment: го то htaccess.net.ru и начитывемся!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<FilesMatch "config.php">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

запрещает доступ к файлу config.php

```
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

запрет к картинкам

Comment: Работает, но не правильно. Теперь не открывает обычные страницы. site.com/page

Comment: КаГбы если запретить картинки то они не будет отображаться на странице, не?

Comment: я запретил php

Comment: Вы запретили открывать пхп и удивляетесь, что пхп не открывается? Фееричненько.

Comment: :)

Comment: Поржал, спасибО!

Comment: Мне нужно запретить прямой вызов php, а вызов через include разрешить.

Comment: Вы таки именно это и сделали)

Answer (score 0):

> Мне нужно запретить прямой вызов php, а вызов через include разрешить.

.htaccess тут не поможет.

Нужно что-то типа:

**index.php**:

```
$GLOBALS['_INC_OTHER'] = 1;
include('other.php');
```

**other.php**:

```
if (empty($GLOBALS['_INC_OTHER'])) exit;
```

Вследствие файл other.php можно будет подключить только через index.php.

Comment: Это я знал, искал другой, более простой способ.

Comment: боюсь что ничего проще вы не найдете